# For $c>b>a$ with $c,b,a\in\Bbb N,c-b=b-a=1$, prove $\frac{a^c}{b^b}+\frac{b^c}{c^b}+\frac{c^c}{a^b}\ge\frac{a^b}{b^a}+\frac{b^b}{c^a}+\frac{c^b}{a^a}$

Tags: inequality

> Given $c>b>a$, also $c-b=b-a=1$ where $c,b,a$ are Natural numbers, prove that
> $$
> \frac{a^c}{b^b}+\frac{b^c}{c^b}+\frac{c^c}{a^b} \geqslant \frac{a^b}{b^a}+\frac{b^b}{c^a}+\frac{c^b}{a^a}
> $$

---

The LHS becomes $$
\frac{a^{b+c} c^b+b^{b+c} a^b+c^{b+c} \cdot b^b}{(a b c)^b},
$$
and the RHS becomes
$$
\frac{a^{b+a} c^a+b^{a+b} a^a+c^{a+b} b^a}{(a b c)^a}.
$$
Now, $a^{b+c}>a^{b+a}$,$c^b>c^a$, $b^{b+c}>b^{b+a}$,$a^b>a^a$,
$c^{b+c}>c^{b+a}$,$b^b>b^a$. So the numerator on LHS is clearly bigger than the numerator on RHS. But $(abc)^{b}>(abc)^{a}$. How do I proceed.
$\textbf{Edit}$: added an important detail.

Comment: Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: @MartinR if you're talking about the source, then it's from our recent test on inequalities

Comment: Unless I make a computation error, that inequality fails e.g. for $(a, b, c) = (3, 6, 7)$.

Comment: @MartinR yes, I realised I have missed an important detail which is added now. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

For $(a, b, c) = (x, x+1, x+2)$ and positive real $x$ is your inequality equivalent to
$$
 2 \frac{(x+2)^{x+1}}{x^{x+1}} - \frac{x^{x+1}}{(x+1)^{x+1}} - \frac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{(x+2)^{x+1}} \ge 0
$$
or
$$
 2 \ge \left( \frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x+2)}\right)^{x+1} + \left( \frac{x(x+1)}{(x+2)^2}\right)^{x+1}
$$
and that is true because both terms on the right are less than one.

Comment: Nice and simple! [+1]

Answer (score -1):

Hint for $a,b,c>3$ we have :

$$\frac{a^c}{b^b}+\frac{b^c}{c^b}+\frac{c^c}{a^b}\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^{c-b}}{3^{c-b-1}}$$

And :

$$\frac{a^b}{b^a}+\frac{b^b}{c^a}+\frac{c^b}{a^a}<3\frac{c^b}{a^a}$$

We have for $c\geq 2(a+b)$:

$$\frac{(a+b+c)^{c-b}}{3^{c-b-1}}-3\frac{c^{b}}{a^{a}}>0$$

For the case $a+b\leq c\leq 2(a+b)$ :

We have :

$$\frac{c^{c}}{a^{b}}-\left(\frac{a^{b}}{b^{a}}+\frac{b^{b}}{c^{a}}+\frac{c^{b}}{a^{a}}\right)>0$$

Or :

$$\frac{c^{c}}{a^{b}}-3\frac{c^{b}}{a^{a}}>0$$

With your constraint we have :

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(x+2\right)^{\left(x+2\right)}}{x^{\left(x+1\right)}}-\frac{\left(x+2\right)^{\left(x+1\right)}}{x^{x}}\geq \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$

$$g(x)=\frac{x^{\left(x+2\right)}}{\left(x+1\right)^{\left(x+1\right)}}-\frac{x^{\left(x+1\right)}}{\left(x+1\right)^{x}}\geq \lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)$$

$$h(x)=\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{\left(x+2\right)}}{\left(x+2\right)^{\left(x+1\right)}}-\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{\left(x+1\right)}}{\left(x+2\right)^{x}}\geq \lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)$$

Reference :

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05874.pdf

Comment: $\frac{a^c}{b^b}+\frac{b^c}{c^b}+\frac{c^c}{a^b}\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^{c-b}}{3^{c-b-1}}$. May you elaborate it a bit on how you got it?

Comment: @MartinR This is a positive constant

Comment: @轻型八神 See the Reference .

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned in the comments, there was an important detail I missed which is added now. Thanks.